# AKS container exec failing after short period

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have an app on AKS that spins up two pods, what I need to do is exe into one to check a few things which I can do immediately after instantiation. However shortly after the exec command starts failing. I'm having trouble finding the root cause of the issue.

The app is from this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app

Here are the commands I'm running.

```bash
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ source envvars.sh
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
azure-vote-back-65c595548d-2bmvx   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          33s
azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          33s
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ watch kubectl get pods
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl get service azure-vote-front
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
azure-vote-front   LoadBalancer   10.0.68.181   20.248.234.249   80:30027/TCP   2m13s
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt-- /bin/bash
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
Error from server (NotFound): pods "azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt--" not found
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt -- /bin/bash
root@azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt:/app# exit
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt -- /bin/bash
root@azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt:/app# exit
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt -- /bin/bash
root@azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt:/app# dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt -- /bin/bash
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "54fb73a731803d4efb811970ede9dc9ef886aba616ece4f4a319a2bce5d863f6": OCI runtime exec failed: /usr/bin/runc did not terminate successfully: exit status 137: : unknown
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$
```

And here are the logs

```bash
dtaylor@DESKTOP-98A8U05:~/development/terraform/aqua_azure_terraform$ kubectl logs  azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt
Checking for script in /app/prestart.sh
Running script /app/prestart.sh
Running inside /app/prestart.sh, you could add migrations to this file, e.g.:

#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Let the DB start
sleep 10;
# Run migrations
alembic upgrade head

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:298: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2023-08-10 00:33:44,775 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2023-08-10 00:33:44,775 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
2023-08-10 00:33:44,782 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2023-08-10 00:33:44,783 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2023-08-10 00:33:44,783 INFO supervisord started with pid 7
2023-08-10 00:33:45,850 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 10
2023-08-10 00:33:45,852 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi' with pid 11
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /app/uwsgi.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Thu Aug 10 00:33:45 2023] ***
compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170516 on 14 December 2017 18:49:24
os: Linux-5.15.0-1042-azure #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 11 17:28:46 UTC 2023
nodename: azure-vote-front-d99b7676c-hxdwt
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.6.3 (default, Dec 12 2017, 16:37:57)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55f1741170f0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 1237056 bytes (1208 KB) for 16 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x55f1741170f0 pid: 11 (default app)
2023-08-10 00:33:46,865 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-08-10 00:33:46,866 INFO success: uwsgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 15, cores: 1)
[pid: 15|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.224.0.4 () {32 vars in 442 bytes} [Thu Aug 10 00:49:10 2023] GET / => generated 950 bytes in 16 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
10.224.0.4 - - [10/Aug/2023:00:49:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 950 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a container runtime security product, correctly preventing an exec shell. For testing, I had to turn enforcement off for this set of pods.